# Sage 50 2014 SData issues

Tags: rest, sage-erp, sdata

Hi I am having a bit of trouble with sdata.  I have been able to see a schema using http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/$schema.  When I try to view accounts etc, through something like the following localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/accounts('ACCOUNTCODE') I get an error errorResourceKindNotFoundUnable to locate the specified object 'accounts50/GCRM/-/accounts'

I have tried several variations of the url based on this resource http://sage.github.io/SData-2.0/

Am I missing I missing some configuration?  I have base the url on the details provided by the Sage.SData.Service.Config.UI.exe utility.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working on a laravel project that uses sData and whilst there appears to be no documentaion on end point I have compiled a list that can be used to gather data from sage accounts here is the list I have used.

```
sagecrmErp2008feeds
```

bankAccounts,
commodities,
commodityGroups,
commodityIdentifiers,
computePrice,
computePriceSchema,
contacts,
contactGroups,
financialPeriods,
interactions,
locations,
operatingCompanies,
Opportunities,
prices,
priceLists,
pricingDocumentLine,
projects,
purchaseOrderDeliveries,
purchaseOrderDeliveryLines,
purchaseOrders,
purchaseOrderLines,
receipts,
salesCredits,
salesCreditLines,
salesInvoices,
salesInvoiceLines,
salesOrderDeliveries,
salesOrderDeliveryLines,
salesOrders,
salesOrderLines,
salesPersons,
salesQuotations,
salesQuotationLines,
taxCodes,
tradingAccounts,
tradingAccountSummaries,
tradingActivities,
unitsOfMeasure,
unitsOfMeasureGroup,

sage2009feeds

emails,
financialAccounts,
notes,
phoneNumbers,
postalAddresses,

these should help you user835440

Comment: there are one or two endpoint that come up with errors because they are are for the SDO data connector they are computePrice and the computePriceSchema

Comment: a good resoure to find available endpoints is http://localhost:5493/sdata/$system/adapters this gives a good list of endpoints and verbs that can be used with assosiated endpoints

Comment: How I can transfer payment line from my application to Sage50 ? which FeedEntry should i use to transfer payment l? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

this is the one I tried should get you started

```
http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/tradingAccounts
```

if want to do a query you simple add this to the end `?select=name&count=3`
and if you want use json just add this `&format=json`
so your full string would read as `http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/tradingAccounts?select=name&count=3&format=json`
hope this helps

Comment: Is there documentation for the GCRM contract somewhere?

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but better than what I have! Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for I may be able to help as I am currently working on a sdata project using the 'sif'

Comment: I thought that GCRM was one of many contracts that defines an interface, so was expecting a document that said what that interface is. Or maybe I don't understand the way the contracts are established or what GCRM is referring to? I see a general schema in the link you provided and thought I'd play around with what's in there to see what is available in our instance.

Comment: here is one to test all the availble endpoints http://localhost:5493/sdata/$system/registry/*/endpoints?where=endPointType%20eq%20%27dataSet%27 check out those results